# Contact Form for User Profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mail-form

I been struggling of thinking of a way to complete this function.

Currently I have a user with a profile. And a general Contact form model that is table-less and doesn't save anything to the database.

My goal is to have a general contact form, In which I can link a contact button on a individual user profile. That contact form when submitted will be sent to the user email specified in the profile attribute. So for example the profile has a field t.string contact_email.

Currently I have the contact model set up where it can send to one individual email. Mainly the app owner.

```
   class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer

      default :to => "stephen@example.com"

       def contact_me(msg)
         @msg = msg

      mail from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
     end
    end
```

My goal is to simply link the

```
        default :to => "stephen@example.com"
```

to something like

```
         default :to => "@profile.contact_email"
```

I have no idea how to specify the user for the form or if its  possible. The process would have to include once the visitor hits contact us the form takes the profile email and uses it as the recipient.

Sorry if this seems like I brung nothing to table to answering I'm just looking for a tip on maybe where to start or how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Don't get into this thing that you would have to specify `to` in default. You can simply send `to` in `mail` method like you are sending `from`, `subject` and other variables.

There are several ways to do it:

1) You can use `hidden_field_tag` to pass along the email of that user like following

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :contact_email, @user.contact_email %>
```

And then on server side, you can have its value through `parmas[:contact_email]`.

2) You can send the email of the user when you can call `contact_me`. Right now, you are only sending one parameter `msg`. So,

```
def contact_me(msg, to)
  @msg = msg

  mail to: to, from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
end
```

And when you call `contact_me`, you can do: `ContactMailer.contact_me(msg, @user.contact_email)` though it may be different depending upon the actual implementation in your code, but the concept would always be same.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm sort of confused on your answer so basically your saying to add the params{:contact_email} to the table-less model's controller? I see what you are saying toward the end but I'm confused on how you are implementing any chance you can. Any way you can give another small quick example?