# Creating a contact form for ruby on rails app users to receive inquiry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, contact-form

Asked this question before, however was confused on the answer that was given and I can't exactly figure out how to implement this.

Previous Question [Contact Form for User Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690845/contact-form-for-user-profile)

I been struggling of thinking of a way to complete this function.

Currently I have a user with a profile. And a general Contact form model that is table-less and doesn't save anything to the database.

My goal is to have a general contact form, In which I can link a contact button on a individual user profile. That contact form when submitted will be sent to the user email specified in the profile attribute. So for example the profile has a field `t.string contactform_email`.

Currently I have the contact model set up where it can send to one individual email. Mainly the app owner.

```
   class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer

      default :to => "stephen@example.com"

       def contact_me(msg)
         @msg = msg

      mail from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
     end
    end
```

My goal is to simply link the

```
    default :to => "stephen@example.com"
```

to something like

```
     default :to => "@profile.contactform_email"
```

A user submitted an answer in the linked question but I can't seem to implement this accurately.

Any help would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sent to different receivers and don't have a default `to` address, then don't use it. Just specify the `to:` option in your `mail` method:

```
# Remove this line
default :to => "stephen@example.com"

# Update your `mail` method
mail to: @msg.contactform_email, from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
```

Make sure your `@msg` has a `contactform_email` field or pass a `@profile` instance of a `to` field to your mailer:

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer

   # default :to => "stephen@example.com"

   def contact_me(msg, profile)
     @msg = msg
     mail to: profile.contactform_email, from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
   end
end

ContactMailer.contact_me(@msg, @profile).deliver_now
```